# Разметка не преобразовывается в объект jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю запрос к другой странице сайта:

```
jQuery.get('my_page', function(result) {
    console.log(jQuery(result));
});
```

В ответе возвращается `html`-разметка этой страницы. Но при попытке преобразовать ее в объект `jQuery` получаем такое:

```
Object(29)
0: #text "
        "
1: <meta charset="UTF-8">
2: #text "
        "
3: <meta name="csrf-token" content="wUQm5qp7pjs2TsOPzU4Zunc6T85jPRCr6ukXGCV2">
​
4: #text "
        "
5: <meta name="yandex-verification" content="9075b8666a01afa5">
6: #text "
        "
7: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
8: #text "
        "
9: <title>
10: #text "
        "
11: <link href="/public/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png">
12: #text "
        "
13: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/style.css">
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: `console.log(result);` - ?

Comment: @Igor, выдает обычную разметку: `<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang = "ru-RU" id = "html">

 <head>

  <meta charset = "UTF-8">

  <meta name = "csrf-token" content...`